# Inequality $\frac{1}{x}>\frac{1}{y}$ when $y>0$ has the same solutions as..

Tags: inequality

Inequality $\frac{1}{x}>\frac{1}{y}$ when $y>0$ has the same solutions as..

a) $x>y$

b) It should say $y>x$

c) $y-x>1$

d) none of three above

Correct answer: d)

My procedure: If x=0,01 and y=0,1 then a) & c) must be false. However, I can not manage to find a counter "example" to b). It seems to me that if the inequality which is posed in the question above should be true then $y>0$ implies that $x>0$. Otherwise the inequality sign does not seem hold. If both variables must be positive then does it not imply that $y>x$?

Comment: There is some typo in your multiple choices...

Comment: What is option (b)?  [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Also, where did option c go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious reason why (b) is wrong is that $y=1$ and $x=0$ is a solution to $y>x$, but is not a solution to $1/x>1/y$. Hence they do not have the same set of solutions.

However, other examples include anything with $y>0$ and $x<0$. That is a solution to $y>x$, but not $1/x>1/y$ with $y>0$.

Explained in another way. It is true that $1/x>1/y$ combined with $y>0$ implies that $x>0$. However, $y>x$ and $y>0$ does not imply that $x>0$, therefore the solution sets cannot be equivalent!

Comment: I understood it as y>x contains the solutions that 1/x>1/y has but y>x has some solutions which 1/x>1/y does not have, thus they do not have equivalent solutions.

Comment: @IGotAQuestion Yes, that is correct. The condition $(y>x) \wedge (y>0)$ has strictly more solutions than $(1/x>1/y) \wedge (y>0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $y>0$

$$\frac1x>\frac1y\iff \frac1x-\frac1y>0\iff \frac{y-x}{xy}>0$$

that is (for $x,y\neq 0$)

- $x>0$ and $x<y$

or

- $x<0$ and $x>y$

Comment: I get the same result but the exam paper says d). 0>y>x but it is not possible according to the condition in the question. It seems to me that the answer should be B) but they said d).

Comment: B indeed is not correct since we need to specify more conditions for the solution.

Comment: In other words y>x works only for x>0, thus option B is wrong.

Comment: But should we not only give an answer to the scenario when y>0 and not when y<0? It seems like you took to account the scenario when 0>x>y, that solution is outside the definition of the inequality?

Comment: I’m referring to x>0 not y.

Comment: For x<0 and y>0 the inequality does not seem to hold. Ex, 1/-1>1/2 if x=-1 and y=2? Oh! That is why it is wrong! Because y>x holds even if y=2, and x=-1, but our given inequality does not, thus they do not have the same answers! Thanks!

Comment: Yes indeed it is true only if x>0 and for x<0 we obtain a condition in contradiction with the given y>0.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{x} > \frac{1}{y} > 0$$ along with $y>0$ implies that $ 0<x<y$

For example $ y=5$ and $x=4,  1/4>1/5$ , and $5>4>0$

Comment: I agree with you, would you say that my answer shert is wrong? Gimusi agreed with my answer sheet and disagreed with you.

Comment: Your answer is correct.  Your example is well posed and clear.